# How to take specific set of characters out of overall string and save to array or list?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string with Unicodes inside of it, and I am trying to extract each unicode from the overall string and save it to a list/array..

This is the overall string:

```
"test &#128311; test &#128153; test &#128313;"
```

I want the following list:

```
1. &#128311; 2. &#128153; 3. &#128313;
```

Right now I am trying the following:

```
string[] emojiSeparators = new string[] { "&#", ";" };
string[] resultEmojis;

resultEmojis = noHtmlEmoji.Split(
  emojiSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

But I am getting the words `"test"` added to the list like below:

[image]

I only want the unicodes saved to my list, so that I can iterate over them and do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest *matching* with a help of *regular expression*:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string[] resultEmojis = Regex
  .Matches(noHtmlEmoji, @"&#[1-9][0-9]{5}(?=;)")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Pattern `&#[1-9][0-9]{5}(?=;)` explained:

```
&#       - &# characters
[1-9]    - digit in 1..9 range
[0-9]{5} - 5 digits in 0..9 range
(?=;)    - ; character which is not included into the match
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EjSvSi)

Comment: thank you, this gives me the array I needed... and thanks for the regex explanation too

Comment: I suspect `{0-5}` might be more accurate

Comment: @Charlieface: I put `{5}` instead of `{0-5}` to match *emoji* only (which have long codes), not every other encoded symbol.

Comment: On that basis I'd probably just parse it and try work out the Unicode class. There are many other characters that have 6 digit Unicode codes.